# Equations for 3D objects

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

How can I generate equations for 3D objects beyond the basics like spheres, cubes and pyramids? For example, how about a diamond?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A diamond, like a pyramid is the intersection of a set of planes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common way to represent 3D shapes is by using implicit equations. The idea is to fabricate a real-valued function $f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$, and then the 3D object is the set $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : f(x,y,z) \le 0 \}$.

Some examples:

$f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 +z^2 - r^2$ gives a sphere of radius $r$.

$f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 - r^2$ gives a cylinder of radius $r$.

$f(x,y,z) = x^2 + 4y^2 +9z^2 - 1$ gives an ellipsoid.

$f(x,y,z) = \max \{ |x|-1, |y|-1, |z|-1 \}$ gives a cube.

$f(x,y,z) = \max \{ |y+z|-1, |z+x|-1, |x+y|-1 \}$ gives a diamond shape.

In general, use of “max”, as in the last two examples, gives you the intersection of simpler shapes.

[This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_surface) tells you about implicit surfaces, described by equations of the form $f=0$. If you just replace the $=0$ by $\le 0$, you generally get a representation of a solid object enclosed by the surface, as I described above.